# jQuery addclass modification

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question How to insert background red color only on One, Three, and Four?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myid li").addClass("redcolor");
});
```

```css
.redcolor {
  background-color: red
}

.abcsize {
  font-size: 36px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myid">
  <li>One</li>
  <li class="abcsize">
    Two
    <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `:eq` selector: https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: `:nth-child` selector: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_nthchild.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `not()` function to get all li's except for the .abcsize and his children

```js
$(function(){
$("#myid li").not('.abcsize,.abcsize li').addClass("redcolor");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style> .redcolor {background-color:red}
.abcsize {font-size:36px}
</style>
<ul id="myid">
<li>One</li>
<li class="abcsize">
    Two
    <ul>
        <li>First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `not` selector, make it

```
$("#myid > li:not(.abcsize)").addClass("redcolor");
```

Also use `>` for only selecting the children

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myid > li:not(.abcsize)").addClass("redcolor");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .redcolor {
    background-color: red
  }
  
  .abcsize {
    font-size: 36px
  }
</style>
<ul id="myid">
  <li>One</li>
  <li class="abcsize">
    Two
    <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: and what if i need to apply on `<li>First</li>` too?)

Comment: @anete.anetes yes, realized it as soon as I posted it.

Comment: madalin ivascu and gurvinder372 I tried ur jquery not work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `not()` function. Its used to select all without `.class`, `#id`, `tag` given as parameter on `not()` function.

```
$(function(){
    $("#myid>li").not(".abcsize,.abcsize>ul>li").addClass("redcolor");
});
```

Comment: Whats your result? BTW, then try with $("#myid li:first-child, #myid li:last-child", #myid li:nth-child(3)).addClass("redcolor");
});

Comment: Sorry brother I forget to save the html